# iframe and fancy box don't run on iphone 6 (ios)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fancybox

I'm new at jquery and fancybox library:
I'm using fancybox and iframe in angular 1 and ionic project, 
everything work fine on browser and android 
only on ios a loader icon appear it doesn't go away.
I put

```
  jQuery(document)
            .ready(
                function () {
                    var selector = '#' + $ctrl.id + ' .hm-meter-wrapper .fancybox';
                    jQuery(selector).fancybox(
                        {
                            minHeight: '480px',
                            autoHeight: true,
                            autoResize: true,
                            autoCenter: true,
                            type: 'iframe',
                            iframe:{
                               preload:false
                            }
                        }
                    );
                });
```

the pop up appear but without content.

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution:
As a side note, the whitelist system is required as of Cordova Tools 5.0.0 (April 21, 2015). For Phonegap Build, that means since cli-5.1.1 (16 Jun 2015)

Add this to your config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"      source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->
```

NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.
Add the following to your index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src *; 
                  style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```